# Using FullCalendar JQuery plugin, why does event end become null if it is equal to event start?

Tags: playframework, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar v2.8.0 and play framework. Event data is mapped to a json object in a calendar controller and then called from the javascript calendar constructor. The event object's start and end dates display correctly when they are not the same, but if they are, the end date is shown as null. Is this default behavior? How can I pass in the end time even if it is equal to the start?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else gets stuck on this, I fixed the problem by adding a String field to the events as they are mapped to the json object. If start and end are the same, I set the value of the String to be displayed. Otherwise, the field is null. Then I put this conditional in the calendar constructor eventClick:

```
if(event.end == null && event.same == null) {
    $('#end').html("Unknown");
} else if (event.end == null && event.same != null) {
    $('#end').html(event.same)
} else {
    $('#end').html(moment(event.end).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
}
```